# VB.Net generated html table to clipboard

Tags: html, vb.net, clipboard, formatted

I have a code, what is generating a HTML formatted table and try to put to the clipboard.

My problem is that, sometimes missing the end of the data or the formatting from the pasted data.

If I write the `htmlStructureStr` variable to the debug window before put to the clipboard, it looks good, all data is in the string.

I guess there is something with the bytecounting, but I can't find the solution.

This is my function (*input variable `tableContent` is a html table string.*):

```
Public Function TableStringToClipboard(ByVal tableContent As String) As Boolean
        Dim htmlStructure As New StringBuilder

#Region "--raw structure of the clipboard data"
        htmlStructure.AppendLine("Version:1.0")
        htmlStructure.AppendLine("StartHTML:0000000001")
        htmlStructure.AppendLine("EndHTML:0000000004")
        htmlStructure.AppendLine("StartFragment:0000000002")
        htmlStructure.AppendLine("EndFragment:0000000003")
        htmlStructure.AppendLine("<html>")
        htmlStructure.AppendLine("<head>")
        htmlStructure.AppendLine("<style>#styleCss#</style>")
        htmlStructure.AppendLine("</head>")
        htmlStructure.AppendLine("<body>")

        htmlStructure.AppendLine("<table cellspacing=0>")
        htmlStructure.AppendLine("<!--StartFragment-->")
        htmlStructure.AppendLine("#tableHtml#")
        htmlStructure.AppendLine("<!--EndFragment-->")
        htmlStructure.AppendLine("</table>")

        htmlStructure.AppendLine("</body>")
        htmlStructure.AppendLine("</html>")
#End Region

#Region "--CSS format definition"

        Dim styleCss As String = ""

            styleCss = " 
            table {border-collapse: collapse;} 
            tr {color:black;
                font-size:11.0pt;
                font-weight: normal;
                font-style:normal;
                text-decoration:none;
                font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;}
            col {mso-width-source:auto;}
            br {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}
            .head
                {padding:2px;
                color:black;
                font-size:11.0pt;
                font-weight:900;
                font-style:normal;
                text-decoration:none;
                font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;

                text-align:left;
                border:.5pt solid #000000;
                white-space:nowrap;
                vertical-align:middle;
                background-color: PowderBlue;
        }
            td
                {padding:2px;
                text-align:general;
                border:.5pt solid #000000;
                white-space:nowrap;
                vertical-align:middle;}"

        htmlStructure.Replace("#styleCss#", styleCss)
#End Region

htmlStructure.Replace("#tableHtml#", tableContent.ToString)

#Region "----ByteCounting"

        Dim byteCounter As System.Text.ASCIIEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII

        Dim value As Integer
        Dim htmlStructureStr As String = htmlStructure.ToString

        value = byteCounter.GetByteCount(Left(htmlStructureStr, htmlStructureStr.IndexOf("<html")))
        htmlStructureStr = htmlStructureStr.Replace("0000000001", value.ToString("D10"))

        value = byteCounter.GetByteCount(Left(htmlStructureStr, htmlStructureStr.IndexOf("<!--StartFragment-->")))
        htmlStructureStr = htmlStructureStr.Replace("0000000002", value.ToString("D10"))

        value = byteCounter.GetByteCount(Left(htmlStructureStr, htmlStructureStr.IndexOf("<!--EndFragment-->")))
        htmlStructureStr = htmlStructureStr.Replace("0000000003", value.ToString("D10"))

        value = byteCounter.GetByteCount(Left(htmlStructureStr, htmlStructureStr.IndexOf("</html>")))
        htmlStructureStr = htmlStructureStr.Replace("0000000004", value.ToString("D10"))
#End Region

        '----put data to clipboard

        My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText(htmlStructureStr, TextDataFormat.Html)

        Return True

    End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649015(v=vs.85).aspx) Says that,

> The only character set supported by the clipboard is Unicode in its UTF-8 encoding. Because the first characters of UTF-8 and ASCII match, the description is always ASCII, but the bytes of the context (starting at StartHTML) could be using any other characters coded in UTF-8.

Use UTF8 encoding as below

```
Dim byteCounter As System.Text.UTF8Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
```

Comment: Hi, yes there is a line before the bytecounting (I missed to write here first):
`htmlStructure.Replace("#tableHtml#", tableContent.ToString)`

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Can you please give some example tableContent?

Comment: Here is an example...

This is a debug print of `htmlStructureStr` before put to clipboard:

[link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b8f3b953a1e531f6bc72775472a092181c05d85e)

Here is how it looks like after pasted to Excel:
[link](http://37.220.129.55/owncloud/index.php/s/j5o1qv2wmrkCIna)

Comment: @norbre Please check the solution I added